# How can I configure IntelliJ to not be a security problem?

Tags: security, intellij-idea

In light of the SolarWinds hack [JetBrains](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/06/us/politics/russia-cyber-hack.html) is implicated in breach of the US government by Russian intelligence. I don't use TeamCity, the implicated program, but I do use (and like) IntelliJ. How can I configure IntelliJ to not be a security problem so I can continue to use it in good conscience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. There is no evidence that JetBrains products were affected.

See the [official response](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/01/07/an-update-on-solarwinds/) for more details:

> **Does this affect your IDEs and other tools?**
>
> Our IDEs are standalone tools and bear no relation to TeamCity, other
> than the fact that we use our own installation of TeamCity to build
> them. We have no evidence that indicates that any of our servers or
> our standalone tools have been tampered with, and much like is the
> case with TeamCity, we run regular security audits on our tools and
> systems.
>
> **Am I safe in using JetBrains tools?**
>
> None of the articles published so
> far, including those referencing investigations by the FBI, as well as
> quotes from SolarWinds themselves, show any evidence that TeamCity has
> any vulnerability or backdoor that would have allowed unauthorized
> access to the build process.
>
> As such we have no knowledge or evidence to believe that any of our
> tools may have been compromised, and consequently do not believe that
> you are at any risk in continuing to use our tools.
>
> We hope that the investigation with SolarWinds is finalised as soon as
> possible and clears up any misrepresentation of our tools and our
> company. We’d also like to reiterate that we offer our full
> cooperation with any governmental agencies and security researchers.
>
> For over 20 years, one of our pillars has been to be transparent,
> honest, and truthful with our customers, and nothing hurts us more
> than seeing unfounded allegations that damage our reputation and
> instil doubt on our customers.
>
> We highly appreciate your support and will keep you updated on any
> progress.